# Can't call callback function from JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-ndk-r5

### *Problem Description*

In ***Android*** application I have class ***`MainClass`***  and in that class I have ***`MainClass`*** which have public function ***`Callback`*** which do some work.

```
public class MainClass {

  public class TestClass {

      TestClass( ) {
          // 
          // Some code goes here.
          //
      }

      public void Callback( ) {
          // 
          // Do some work. 
          //
      } 
   }
}
```

### *Question*

How I can call ***`Callback`*** method from JNI, I use this way but my application crashes.

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass( env, "com/application/Test/MainClass/TestClass" );
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID( env, cls, "Callback", "()V" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using GetObjectClass instead of FindClass